# How a does a RF magnetic field interact with trapped atoms in evaporative cooling?

Tags: magnetic-fields, atomic-physics, radio-frequency, cold-atoms

In the paper “Evaporative Cooling of Trapped Atoms,” [*Advances in Atomic Molecular And Optical Physics* **37**, 181–236 (1986)] by Wolfgang Ketterle and N. J. Van Druten, they claimed the matrix element coupling the trappable state atomic state $|F,m_F\rangle$ and the untrappable state $|F,m_{F}\pm1\rangle$ is $$\Omega=\frac{1}{4}g\mu_BB_0(\hat{e}_{RF}\times\hat{e}_z)\sqrt{F(F+1)-m_F(m_F\pm1)}.$$
The RF field is $\vec{B}_{RF}=B_0\hat{e}_{RF}\cos(\omega_{RF}t)$; $g$ is the atomic $g$-factor; and the trapping field points along the quantization axis $\hat{e}_z$.

The potential energy in a magnetic environment is $-\vec{m}\cdot\vec{B}.$ So I expect the parallel component to the trapping field contribute the potential term coupling two states but the result is the normal component. If so, I should not have the coupling potential term due to the rf-field because atoms in the trapping field are pointing along the trapping field.

Why is it so? For me this result seems contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many years ago, I actually discussed something very closely related to this question of the authors of that paper.  It's a tricky point, and I initially was confused about the same kind of thing.

Consider the atom as just a two-state system, involving the two magnetic sublevels involved in the transition:  $|F,m_{F}\rangle\equiv\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$ and $|F,m_{F}+1\rangle\equiv\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]$. Then the effective Hamiltonian is
$$H_{{\rm eff}}=-g\mu_{B}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{B}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
\\=H_{0}-\frac{1}{2}g\mu_{B}B_{0}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right]+g\mu_{B}(B_{RF,z}F_{z}+B_{RF,+}F_{+}+B_{RF,-}F_{-})\cos(\omega_{RF}t),$$
where $H_{0}=E_{0}\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$ is proportional to the identity. The constant $E_{0}$ depends on $B_{0}$, $F$, $m_{F}$, etc.; however, it is a constant that does not affect the rate of transitions between the two states of interest.

If there is only a $z$-component to the RF field, then the interaction term contains just
$$g\mu_{B}B_{RF}B_{z}F_{z}\cos(\omega_{RF}t)=g\mu_{B}B_{RF}\left[\begin{array}{cc}m_{F}\cos(\omega_{RF}t) & 0 \\ 0 & (m_{F}+1)\cos(\omega_{RF}t)\end{array}\right].$$
This is a time-dependent Hamiltonian, but it is still *diagonal* in the original basis.  The energies have changed, but the eigenstates have not, because the interaction (in this two-state basis) is a linear combination of $\cos(\omega_{RF}t)$ and $\sigma_{3}\cos(\omega_{RF}t)$.  In contrast, the $x$- and $y$-components $B_{RF,x}\equiv\frac{1}{2}(B_{RF,+}+B_{RF,-})$ and $B_{RF,x}\equiv\frac{1}{2i}(B_{RF,+}-B_{RF,-})$ multiply $m_{F}$-raising and -lowering operators $F_{+}$ and $F_{-}$ (which are proportional to $\sigma_{\pm}$ in the two-state basis), and these clearly can change the state of the system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!